# Configuration of foreign key relation by ef fluent conventions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, conventions

I've got a problem with EF Fluent Configuration. I had to split my base Entity class into one class and few interfaces. I am trying to make configuration for non conventional fk key -> navigation property relation.

The problem is:

```
modelBuilder.Types<IAuditable>()
                .Configure(x => x.Property(y => y.CreatedByUser)
```

Do not expose any kind of API which lets me configure this relation.

I've tried to look for some kind of annotation to configure it in (DataAnnotations like way - decorating properties on interface is pointless)

```
modelBuilder.Types<IAuditable>()
            .Configure(x => x.Property(y => y.CreatedByUser)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute {IsUnique = true}));
```

Yet I can't find anything like ForeignKeyDataAnnotation. Is it even possible to do such a thing in EF6?

EDIT:

I am fully aware i shouldn't mix DataAnnotations with Fluent Configuration yet there are things which are unfortunately not possible in Fluent (at least thats what i got in my research). (this is how i Auditable looks like).

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    public int CreatedBy { get; set;}
    public int CreatedByUser {get; set;}

}
```

(Till this point i had one BaseEntity class decorated with Foreign Key Attribiute  -> it was the only place in app where i used DataAnnotations).

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. You want to configure a navigation property for all entities that implement a specific interface? If so, you are going to fail most probably, since navigation properties need to be configured on entities.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want. Before "the split" the configuration was done by attributes in BaseClass. The one option is to rename properties in interface to match convention (yet this would break other dependencies in app like AutoMapper mappings).